# Ranking within a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ranking, rank

I have a seemingly simple ranking-type problem associated with php arrays, unfortunately after much research it has defeated me:

I have a simple array where the keys are names of people and the values are just associated numbers:

```
$myArray = Array("David"=>36, "James"=>24, "Sarah"=>70, "Mary"=>55);
```

Here’s the challenge: *Given* a name, what is their *rank* within the array? For example: Sarah=rank1; It seems simple because I figured I could just sort the array by the values then loop though to the required name to get the rank. However, weirdly when I sort the array it just unhelpfully returns 1!

```
print_r(asort($myArray)) = 1 (??)
```

I suppose I could put the array in an MySQL table but that seems a bit heavy handed. Is anyone aware of a php solution? Where am I going wrong with the sort? I've read the documentation [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and it seems asort is the appropriate function (preserves association and sorts on values).

Thanks
The Grinch

Comment: The return value of [`asort()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) is `bool`, 1 as return value means `TRUE` and means that the array's been sorted....

Answer (score 1):

[`asort`](http://php.net/asort) function returns a boolean and sort the given array as a reference

```
var_dump(asort($myArray)) = bool(true)
```

If you `print_r($myArray)` after this previous line, you'll get your sorted array in `$myArray`

EDIT: Re-read.

Try doing this to get your ranking numerously:

```
<?php
    /* asort = Lower num to Upper */
    asort($myArray);
    /* arsort = Upper one to lower */
    // arsort($myArray);
    $ranks = array_fill(1,count($myArray),'foo');
    $ranked = array_combine(array_flip($myArray),array_keys($ranks));
    /* Output */
    print_r($ranked);
    /* Array ( [James] => 1 [David] => 2 [Mary] => 3 [Sarah] => 4 )  */
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

(Edited - works now)

Kind of ugly but this should work:

```
arsort($origArr);
$rankedArr = array_keys($origArr);
foreach ($rankedArr as $rank => $person) {
    if ($person == 'Sarah') {
        echo $rank + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

What you're doing is first sorting by values, then you're dropping those values and just getting an indexed list of people. Their *key value + 1* is their rank. (because first is 0, right?)

EDIT2 - slightly cleaner:

```
arsort($origArr);
$rankedArr = array_keys($origArr);
$finalRanks = array_flip($rankedArr);
$rank = $finalRanks['Sarah'] + 1;
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

`asort` returns bool value, as described [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).